# Error adding IOS Apple account to Visual Studio 17.7 Preview 2

Tags: ios, visual-studio, provisioning-profile, api-key

I am trying to add my Apple Account to VS 2022 preview. I keep getting "Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens Version 6.22.0.0

I used the exact same API key info on VS for Mac with no problem. I have .Net 6, 7, and 8 installed.
Anyone had this problem and fixed it?

[image]

Comment: I did find a work around and that is to roll back to Preview 1 if that helps anyone.
17.7.0 Preview 1

Comment: Thanks for this. Rolling back worked for me also.